# get foreground console / find active X server

Tags: c, linux, console, xorg, xserver

I'd like to programmatically find the X server that is attached to the console, meaning currently controlled by mouse/keyboard/screen.
I assumed there is a clean way to get the current vt (using `/dev/console`?). The `fgconsole` [code](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kbd/kbd_1.15.2.orig.tar.gz) (fgconsole.c, getfd.c) made me doubt a bit.
While

```
struct vt_stat vtInfo;
ioctl(fdConsole, VT_GETSTATE, &vtInfo);
```

seems to be what i want, the code to retrieve a valid console fd seems somewhat unreliable - although 5 files are tested (rw/w/r each), it still fails if called inside a terminal emulation (xterm).  I can probably live with that, but it doesn't really feel good...
(Note: of course a xterm cannot be the console - we are talking about querying the fgconsole inside an xterm).

Next, I would have to map the vt (eg. vt7) to an X display.
However, I'd rather not rely on

```
ps aux | grep X
```

to accomplish that... Is there a more reliable way?
Could I maybe connect to all the X servers listed in `/tmp/.X11-unix/` and ask them about their vt?
Or even directly get their attached-to-console ('active') state? I could not find an obvious way to do that with Xlib, probably because the X server API is agnostic to vts, but maybe there is an extension for this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the **/proc** fs :) It seems to provide everything i need. I have not yet cast this into C code, but this should work pretty good:

- look for open X displays (and their Names, eg. **:0**) in **/tmp/.X11-unix/**
- look for these sockets in **/proc/net/unix**, get their inodes
- look for processes in **/proc/[PID]/** that have a vt open: `ls -la /proc/*/fd/ | grep /dev/tty` - if they also have one of the socket inodes in their open file descriptors, they should be an X server, else a tty. Of course, **/proc/[PID]/exe** helps, but may be less reliable.

The output of `cat /proc/net/unix | grep -a '/tmp/.X11-unix/X'` suggests, that there is always a socket of the form `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` and many of the form `@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` (note the @). I wonder if it is a save assumption that there is always exactly one process (the X server) listening on the former.